Custom Teams App using Blazor published in Azure not working
I'm begginer creating a Teams App Blazor in Visual Studio 2022(Not Visual Studio Code), I already created the Teams APP using another custom teams app that I downloaded and after modify it works Fine when I executed Locally directly from VS2022. Right now I'm in the step to publish it in Azure and I already did and I have the link in Azure but it doesn't work when I click it.
I already Published in "Azure App Service (Windows)" following the wizard in Visual Studio 2022 and the process was successfully Published from Visual Studio 2022, if I go to Azure account I can see the link created when, I click on the webpage created by Azure and says "An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded. Reload" and activating the Developer Tools in the web browser I see 2 Errors but when I execute the Teams APP directly in Visual Studio 2022 the application looks fine actually when I execute it in VS2022 the Team App appears in Teams and I can execute it without problem, I mean, the APP doesn't has errors.
Is there something that I missing? For example the files manifest.json, .env.local, .env.local, launchSettings.json, etc. should I need to modify something before publish it?
Why the webpage doesn't work directly from azure after published? But when I execute it from VS2022 the App works fine(When I execute it from VS2022 the link is "https://localhost:44302" because is locally and works fine... But it's not working from Azure.
Is there another configuration or values that I need to change in VS2022 before publish it in Azure?
SORRY But I'm desperate because the Teams APP works fine locally but I'm not able to executed from Azure after was published, I don't know what else should I modify.
These are the 2 errors that appears using the Web Developer Tool when I click directly the webpage created in Azure when was published:
ERROR #1:
"Error: There was an unhandled exception on the current circuit, so this circuit will be terminated. For more details turn on detailed exceptions by setting 'DetailedErrors: true' in 'appSettings.Development.json' or set 'CircuitOptions.DetailedErrors'. blazor.server.js:1:116297
    log h ttps://basicblazortabapp20240821103153.azurewebsites.net/_framework/blazor.server.js:1
    tr h ttps://basicblazortabapp20240821103153.azurewebsites.net/_framework/blazor.server.js:1
    er h ttps://basicblazortabapp20240821103153.azurewebsites.net/_framework/blazor.server.js:1
    _invokeClientMethod h ttps://basicblazortabapp20240821103153.azurewebsites.net/_framework/blazor.server.js:1
    _invokeClientMethod h ttps://basicblazortabapp20240821103153.azurewebsites.net/_framework/blazor.server.js:1
    _processIncomingData h ttps://basicblazortabapp20240821103153.azurewebsites.net/_framework/blazor.server.js:1
    onreceive h ttps://basicblazortabapp20240821103153.azurewebsites.net/_framework/blazor.server.js:1
    _poll h ttps://basicblazortabapp20240821103153.azurewebsites.net/_framework/blazor.server.js:1"

ERROR #2:
"Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot send data if the connection is not in the 'Connected' State.
    send h ttps://basicblazortabapp20240821103153.azurewebsites.net/_framework/blazor.server.js:1
    _sendMessage h ttps://basicblazortabapp20240821103153.azurewebsites.net/_framework/blazor.server.js:1
    _sendWithProtocol h ttps://basicblazortabapp20240821103153.azurewebsites.net/_framework/blazor.server.js:1
    send h ttps://basicblazortabapp20240821103153.azurewebsites.net/_framework/blazor.server.js:1
    endInvokeJSFromDotNet h ttps://basicblazortabapp20240821103153.azurewebsites.net/_framework/blazor.server.js:1
    beginInvokeJSFromDotNet h ttps://basicblazortabapp20240821103153.azurewebsites.net/_framework/blazor.server.js:1"



You can refer the below document-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/build-your-first-blazor-web-app/3-exercise-configure-environment?pivots=vscode
